# Estimating Poisson rate and using the resulting distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The following table shows the frequency of arrival of patients at a health clinic ina 15-minute time interval. What is the probability that more than 6 patients will arrive in next half an hour?

```
Number of customers  : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Observed frequency   : 1 4 5 6 4 3 2
```

The problem I face is here random variable is defined for number of intervals but we have to find the probability for number of customers How is that possible?

I am new to Statistics Please help me with ideas or examples

Comment: Have you learned about parameter estimation, specifically maximum likelihood estimation?

Comment: no I haven't done that part.Is it okay to consider P(2X>=6)?

Comment: My doubt is how to convert this 15 min time interval to 30 minutes

Comment: Double the Poisson rate.

Comment: @Tommik's deleted answer is skeletal but I think completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This solution does not use a Poisson distribution, it uses the observed/empirical distribution to estimate the answer. For the solution using a Poisson assumption, see BruceET's solution.

You want to think about the next half hour as two distinct events, each of 15 minute intervals.

Let $X$ be the number of arrivals in the first 15 minutes, and $Y$ be the number of arrivals in the second 15 minutes. Then, the number of arrivals in the next 30 minutes can be represented by $ Z = X + Y $.

First, we need the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. We can get to that using the number of observations for number of observed patients. For example, out of a total of 25 observations, 0 patients were observed 1 time, so the probability of 0 is $1/25  = 0.04$. One patient was observed 4 times, for a probability of $4/25 = 0.16$. Continuing on through all observations, we arrive at the following probability distribution:

| Number of Patients | Frequency | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4% |
| 1 | 4 | 16% |
| 2 | 5 | 20% |
| 3 | 6 | 24% |
| 4 | 4 | 16% |
| 5 | 3 | 12% |
| 6 | 2 | 8% |

Since $Y$ is just another 15 minute interval, we can assume it has the same distribution as $X$.

Then, we get to the distribution of $Z$ by considering possible combinations of $X$ and $Y$. For example, $Z = 0$ can only happen if $X = 0$ and $Y = 0$:

$$ P[Z = 0] = P[X = 0 \cap Y = 0]. $$

But, $Z = 2$ can happen if $X = 2$ and $Y = 0$ OR $X = 1$ and $Y = 1$ OR $X = 0$ and $Y = 2$:

$$ P[Z = 2] = P[(X = 2 \cap Y = 0) \cup (X = 1 \cap Y = 1) \cup (X = 0 \cap Y = 2)]. $$

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent events, you can break this up like so:

$$ P[Z = 2] = P[(X = 2 \cap Y = 0) \cup (X = 1 \cap Y = 1) \cup (X = 0 \cap Y = 2)] $$
$$ = P[X = 2 \cap Y = 0] + P[X = 1 \cap Y = 1] + P[X = 0 \cap Y = 2] $$
$$ = P[X = 2]*P[Y = 0] + P[X = 1]*P[Y = 1] + P[X = 0]*P[Y = 2] $$
$$ = 0.20*0.04 + 0.16*0.16 + 0.04*0.20 $$
$$ = 0.0416 $$

Once you go through the different possible combinations, you arrive at the following distribution for $Z$:

| Number of Patients | Probability |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.16% |
| 1 | 1.28% |
| 2 | 4.16% |
| 3 | 8.32% |
| 4 | 12.96% |
| 5 | 15.68% |
| 6 | 16.64% |
| 7 | 15.04% |
| 8 | 11.52% |
| 9 | 7.68% |
| 10 | 4.00% |
| 11 | 1.92% |
| 12 | 0.64% |

Then, what you're looking for is

$$ P[Z > 6] = 15.04\% + 11.52\% + ... + 0.64\% = 40.80\%. $$

Comment: Method is basically sound, but no need to derive PDF of POIS(6) from sum of two random variables distributed POIS(3). You lose a little accuracy by rounding and by stopping the infinite sum at $P(Z=12).$ Would be more accurate and easier to subtract $P(X \le 6)$ from $1.$ // I believe answ to four places is 0.3937, as in my answer. // (+1) anyhow.

Comment: Completely forgot that the question involved a Poisson distribution by the time I finished reading it smh

Answer (score 1):

**Using data to estimate Poisson rate per 15 min.** Let $k = 0, 1, \dots 6,$ and $f_k = 1, 4, \dots, 2.$
Then there are $n = \sum_{i=k}^6 f_k = 25$ fifteen minute periods with an average of $\bar X = \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^6 kf_k
= 3.$ So the average fifteen minute period has $\hat \lambda_{15} = \bar X = 3$ arrivals.  (See @heropup's Comment on estimation. Computations using R as a calculator.)

```
k = 0:6
f = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2)
n = sum(f); n
[1] 25
sum(k*f)/n
[1] 3
```

**Poisson rate for 30 min.** Then the number $Y$ of arrivals over half an hour (30 minutes) can be modeled as a Poisson random variable with arrival rate $6.$ That is,
$\lambda_{30} = 2\lambda_{15} = 6.$
Now, we can assume $Y\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=6).$

**Using Poisson PDF.** You seek

$$P(Y > 6) = 1 - P(Y \le 6) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^6 P(Y=k)\\
= 1-\sum_{k=0}^6 e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = 0.3937,$$

where the next-to-last step uses the Poisson PDF (or PMF).

You can use a calculator to find and sum the required six terms. A statistical calculator might be able to find
the sum automatically. In R, where `ppois` stands for
the CDF of a Poisson distribution, the computation
is shown below:

```
1 - ppois(6, 6)
[1] 0.3936972
```

**Rough normal approximation.** Sometimes, if $\lambda$ is large enough, Poisson probabilities can be found using a normal approximation.
I don't know whether you are expected to use this method, because $\lambda = 6$ is a little too small for a good
approximation.

If so, here is a start:

$$P(Y > 6) = P(Y>6.5) = P\left(\frac{Y-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} > \frac{6.5 - 6}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\\
\approx P(Z > 0.2041) \approx 0.42,$$
where the numerical value of the probability is from printed normal CDF tables. (Look in the margins of the table for z-values $0.20$ and $0.21.)$

The first equality amounts to a 'continuity correction'; the last line uses the normal approximation. If you use
this method, you should (a) justify each step and (b) comment that it is only a rough approximation.

Because $E(Y) = 6, Var(Y) = 6,$ and $SD(Y) = \sqrt{6},$ we can compute the
normal approximation directly in R without standardization as shown below:

```
1 - pnorm(6.5, 6, sqrt(6))
[1] 0.4191282
```

In the figure below the black vertical bars show the PDF of $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=6),$ the red curve is the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=6, \sigma=\sqrt{6}),$ and the vertical dotted line is at
$Y = 6.5.$ The exact answer is the sum of the heights of the bars to the right of that dotted line. Finally, an approximate answer (a little too big) is the area under
the density curve to the right of the vertical dotted line.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
k = 0:15;  PDF = dpois(k, 6)
plot(k, PDF, type="h", lwd=3, main="PDF of POIS(6)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 6, sqrt(6)), add=T, col="red")
 abline(v = 6.5, lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="blue")
```